# Error: The application has failed to start because the side by side configuration is incorrect

Tags: windows-10

When I tries to run Glary Utilities 5.46, the following error message appears.
'**The application has failed to start because the side by side configuration is incorrect please see the application event log or use the command line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail**'

I had posted a question in Microsoft Community and did what the support engineer said, including repairing corrupted files with RestoreHealth and re-installation in compatible mode, but the side by side configuration error still appears. What else can I do?

The following have already been installed. http://fud.community.services.support.microsoft.com/Fud/FileDownloadHandler.ashx?fid=e012ca9a-6548-47ad-a7e9-a0777b03746e

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling all msvc packages, and re-install all of them in ascending order(msvc 2005 to 2013)?, because this way solved the same issue for me., Also, If your OS is 64-bit and you have to install 32 and 64-bit packages.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that before asking a question here, but it did not help. However, the problem has already been fixed by a clean installation of Windows, which took a shorter time than searching for an alternative solution had.

Comment: Related post - [Side-By-Side error when installing Opera](https://superuser.com/q/1126656/374397)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happens when a required Visual C++ Runtime is missing. Start the [Command prompt with admin rights](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2790-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-10-a.html) and run this command:

```
SxsTrace Trace -logfile:SxsTrace.etl
```

Now run Glary Utilities and go back to the command prompt press `ENTER` to generate the `SxsTrace.etl`. Now type this:

```
sxstrace Parse -logfile:SxSTrace.etl -outfile:SxSTrace.txt
```

Now open the `SxSTrace.txt` trace and look which VC++ runtime is missing.

Comment: The problem has already been fixed by a clean installation of Windows, which took a shorter time than searching for an alternative solution had. 

Anyway, thanks for your help..

Comment: Hi See if you can help me with [THIS](http://superuser.com/questions/1126656/side-by-side-error-when-installing-opera)

Comment: This helped me a lot, but as a quick aside - it didn't indicate a missing Visual C++ Runtime in my case.  It was actually malformed XML in the config file.  Which made this a very misleading error.

Comment: In my case, I see `ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC90.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86"`. After short googling, I installed `Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)` and that fixes it.

Comment: @Rosdi yes VC90 is 2008, while VC80 is 2005.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same error for `Chrome.exe` yesterday,
after one day now i found the reason

I also try

- uninstall and reinstall Microsoft Visual C++ 2013,2015 Redistributable
- Edit some registry values (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide\Winners)

**but not solved**

---

In Chrome application folder a file should exists (removed) that `92.0.4505.0.manifest` named

Its name is same as your application version, like `<APP_VERSION>.manifest`

That its content should be

```
<assembly
  xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <assemblyIdentity
      name='92.0.4505.0'
      version='92.0.4505.0'
      type='win32'/>
  <file name='chrome_elf.dll'/>
</assembly>
```

Now its works fine !

Comment: Confirming I also fixed this error with this answer.
Specifically I created a text file "<APP_VERSION>.manifest" in c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\<APP_VERSION>

The content of the file is the text in above making sure to update the "name" and "version" lines with the <APP_VERSION> from the directory path.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while trying to launch winMerge diff tool. I checked the solution [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-error-the-application-has-failed-to/5c6a015e-4162-491d-b7d9-f3b13612e304?auth=1):

> Method 1:
>
> Kindly download and install Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable
>   Package  from below given link and check if it helps:
>
> Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40784

But when I ran the installer, I realized that `Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package` was already installed on my computer and it was asking for repair instead. To be on safe side I just ran the repair wizard once.

Then I uninstalled and reinstalled WinMerge tool as mentioned in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEIb40mJ2yo) youtube video. After that I rebooted my computer then finally winMerge worked smoothly.