# Side-By-Side error when installing Opera

Tags: opera, opera-10

**Problem**:

When I downloaded and tried installing *Opera Developer 38.0.2205.0* from [Here](https://opera-next.en.uptodown.com/windows/download), I got the following error.

[image]

**What Have I tried**:

1. I did a google search and came across [This](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/608966/the-application-has-failed-to-start-because-its-side%E2%80%90by%E2%80%90side/) link which mentions that the problem went away after the *Security Update for Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package (KB2538243)* was installed. I did exactly that. I downloaded and installed the files from [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=26368) but the problem did not go away.
2. I searched SuperUser and came across [Error: The application has failed to start because the side by side configuration is incorrect](https://superuser.com/questions/1057460/error-the-application-has-failed-to-start-because-the-side-by-side-configuratio). I did exactly as suggested and generated the **sysxtrace.txt**. Here is the extract from it. I do not understand the error.

**sysxtrace.txt**

[image]

**Question**:

Is there something very basic that I am missing or do I need to do something else to install this file

Comment: this looks like a corrupted installer. Get the installer directly from Opera: https://net.geo.opera.com/opera/developer?utm_medium=sm&utm_source=desktop_blog&utm_campaign=developer also version 38 is very old.

Comment: Awesome! That worked :) You may want to put it as an answer?

Comment: @magicandre1981: would you be putting it as your answer? if not then i will delete this question.

Comment: I need some sleep and can't be here 24h per day ;) I posted it as answer

Comment: What? You have life other than stackoverflow?????? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message "`Line 0: XML Syntax error`" looks like a corruption of the installer. So The installer is damaged. Opera Dev 38 is a also an older version. [Get the latest version directly from Opera](https://net.geo.opera.com/opera/developer?utm_medium=sm&utm_source=desktop_blog&utm_campaign=developer) and not from siuch a strange 3rd party page.